# How to disable a warning in code generated by a maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, openapi, javac, suppress-warnings

I am generating sources as part of a Java 17 maven build using version 5.4.0 (latest release as of 2022-04-05) of `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`.  Works fine.

Unfortunately the generated source uses a deprecated method so the Java compiler fairly emits a warning.

```
java: configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature,boolean) in com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper has been deprecated
```

Normally I would add a `@SuppressWarnings` snippet but as this is generated code that is not stored in git, that will not work here.

I have full control of the Maven project.  Can I disable this warning (and just that one)?

Comment: The warning is being generated by the java-compiler which compiles the generated code.. This means the generated code is using deprecated methods/classes etc. In consequence there is only one way. You have to. inform the author of the plugin to get an updated version (or at least report that problem)...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you.  I was wondering if there might be a compiler setting or other configuration that would do this, but apparently I thought of the .NET compiler.  Perhaps ecj can.  I'll live with it for now.

Comment: Of course you can configure the compiler to ignore such warnings `-Xlint:-deprecation` ... but that will ignore all such warnings...for the whole code..